# ExtJS: Allowing automatic parsing of nested data in associated models

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I can't get the framework to parse correctly. I have no problem setting associations up to load nested data asynchronously when the generated store names are the lower-case, pluralized name of the associated model (i.e. when generating a `posts` store from nested `Post` models). But here, I'm having trouble finding the right configs to allow the framework to automatically parse data supplied in the *same* response, when the association key has nothing to do with the associated model name:

**App.model.Foo.js**

```
// Bar
Ext.define('Bar', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [...],

    belongsTo: 'App.model.Foo'
});

// Foo
Ext.define('App.model.Foo', {
    extend: 'App.model.Base',

    fields: [...],

    hasMany: {
        model: 'Bar',
        name: 'children',             // trying to allow parsing from 'children'
        associationKey: 'children',   // property, but not working
        reader: 'json'
    }
});
```

**Data**

```
{
    data: {
        // Foo fields
        children: [{
             // Bar objects
        }]
    },
    success: true
}
```

`children` is added as a store getter-function on `Foo` models, but the data is not parsed from `children` key in response data.

Comment: anything? I keep reading over the docs, and this *should* work ... but doesnt, no?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example (tested using ExtJS 4.2.x)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.define('Bar', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['barfield'],
        belongsTo: 'Foo'
    });


    Ext.define('Foo', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

        fields: ['foofield'],

        hasMany: {
            model: 'Bar',
            name: 'children',
            associationKey: 'children'
        },

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'
            }
        }
    });

    Foo.load("PARAM", {
        scope: this,
        callback: function (record, operation, success) {
            console.log(record.get("foofield"));

            var children = record.children();   // get the store
            console.log(children.getAt(0).get("barfield"));
            console.log(children.getAt(1).get("barfield"));
        }
    });
});
```

The JSON data is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "foofield": "value",

        "children": [
            {
                "barfield": "bval1"
            },
            {
                "barfield": "bval2"
            }
        ]
    },
    "success": true
}
```